# Mysql regroup data for chart

Tags: mysql

I try to build a chart from a mysql table 'sells'. Every month (column 'date'), 3 users (column 'user') save a value (column 'value').

```
id | user  | date       | value
--------------------------------
1  | 1     | 2014-01-01 | 556
2  | 2     | 2014-01-01 | 703
3  | 3     | 2014-01-01 | 200
4  | 1     | 2014-02-01 | 240
5  | 2     | 2014-02-01 | 950
6  | 3     | 2014-02-01 | 120
7  | 1     | 2014-03-01 | 450
8  | 2     | 2014-03-01 | 560
9  | 3     | 2014-03-01 | 704
10 | 1     | 2014-04-01 | 208
11 | 2     | 2014-04-01 | 254
....
```

I try to build a chart that shows for a selected user and a given interval of time :
- the personnal value for the selected user
- the minimum value between all users
- the maximum value between all users

Here is what I try to get this result, for the user '1' :

```
date       | value | min | max
--------------------------------
2014-01-01 | 556   | 200 | 703
2014-02-01 | 240   | 120 | 950
2014-03-01 | 450   | 450 | 704
2014-04-01 | 208   | 208 | 254
...
```

I think it is possible to get this result with a single mysql query, but I dont't manage to do it. Anyone ?

Comment: Can you do *any* of it?

Comment: The aim is to get the data for a specific user. The id user will be given as a variable.
For example : 
    SELECT ... FROM sells WHERE .. AND user=1

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: Sorry for my english. I am not sure to understand what you mean.
I've tried this query : 

`SELECT value, MIN(value) AS min, MAX(value) AS max 
FROM sells 
WHERE 
user=1 AND date BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-04-01 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date`

Comment: OK - well that's pretty close...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
     , min_value
     , max_value 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT date
            , MIN(value) min_value
            , MAX(VALUE) max_value 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY date
     ) y
    ON y.date = x.date
 ORDER  
    BY x.user
     , x.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Strawberry. I just added the condition to filter on the user :

```
SELECT x.*
     , min_value
     , max_value 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT date
            , MIN(value) min_value
            , MAX(VALUE) max_value 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY date
     ) y
    ON y.date = x.date
 WHERE user = 1
 ORDER  
    BY x.date;
```